# In Veins does "RecievedBroadcasts" also consist of "SNIRLostPackets" and "RXTXLostPackets"?

Tags: omnet++, wireless, veins

I would just like to know if the value of "RecievedBroadcasts" for each of the node in Veins also consists of the packets lost or does it just give the number of successful packet receptions. That is if I want to calculate the packet loss ratio, then would it be TotalLostPackets/RecievedBroadcasts or TotalLostPackets/(RecievedBroadcasts + TotalLostPackets).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet to find out exactly how statistics are logged is to look into [the source code of Mac1609_4](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc).

You will find that the `ReceivedBroadcasts` scalar logs the value of variable `statsReceivedBroadcasts` which is increased via a method called from `handleLowerMsg`, so only when the Mac layer successfully decoded data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Christoph.